# React native 0.63 , how to clip element inside borderRadius on android?

Tags: android, react-native, border-radius

I'm trying to clip element with border-radius on an android device, just like on the iPhone.
Do you know how?

I set a `borderRadius` on a `FlatList`.

On iOS the `FlatList` items are cut by the `borderRadius`, but on android, they exceed the `borderRadius`.

[image: Gif of the problem]

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Package json:

```
{
  "name": "BorderRadius",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

const texts = [
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>
        <View style={styles.spacer} />
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={texts}
          renderItem={(obj) => (
            <View style={styles.card} key={obj.index}>
              <Text>{obj.item}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
  },
  spacer: {
    height: 50,
  },
  card: {
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 16,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  list: {
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 75,
    borderTopRightRadius: 75,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});

export default App;
```